# ~TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') ~ shown even after trying to return a mock value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
    at SubmissionDataComponent.getLookupData (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/ViewModules/shared-components/submission-data/submission-data.component.ts:263:32)
    at SubmissionDataComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/ViewModules/shared-components/submission-data/submission-data.component.ts:211:10)
    at callHook (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2539:1)
    at callHooks (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2508:1)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2459:1)
    at refreshView (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9586:1)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9685:1)
    at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10916:1)
    at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10941:1)
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22961:1)
```

This is the error that is showing up. I created a mockService for commonUtilty and then returned a mock value which I think is getting subscribed to. My initial thought was since lookup$ property is bonded to the service, if mocking the service and returning a mock value would fix it but the problem still seems to be there. Is there any fix for this problem?

.ts file

```
lookupsToBind=['a','b','c']
 lookup$ = this.commonUtilty.initializeLookupList(this.lookupsToBind)
 private getLookupData() {
    this.lookup$['example'].subscribe(lookup => {
      this.currencyLookup = lookup;
      // this.currencyLookup = cur
    });
    this.lookup$['example2'].subscribe(lookup => {
      this.planTypeLookup = lookup;
    });
}
```

.spec.ts file (Edit: annotated the mocked return value)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ApiRequestService, ValidationUtilService,CommonUtilty, I18nService, MultiLingualService, LookupDataService, InteractService, WorkqueueService, AppMetadataHandler } from 'app';
import { MetadataService } from 'app/BaseFramework/core/http/metadata.service';
import { NgZorroAntdModule } from 'app/ng-zorro.module';
import { NewBusinessAppSettings } from 'app/ViewModules/Newbusiness/newbusiness-configs/newbusiness-app-settings.config';
import { CustomHookService } from 'app/ViewModules/shared-services/custom-hook/custom-hook.service';
import { lookup } from 'dns';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { SubmissionDataComponent } from './submission-data.component';


describe('SubmissionDataComponent', () => {
  let component: SubmissionDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SubmissionDataComponent>;
    let mockValidationUtilService;
    let mockApiRequestService;
    let mockFormBuilder;
    let mockCommonUtilty;
    let mockI18nService;
    let mockMultiLingualService;
    let mockTranslateService;
    let mockLookupDataService;
    let mockInteractService;
    let mockWorkqueueService;
    let mockAppMetadataHandler;
    let mockNewBusinessAppSettings
    let mockCustomHookService;
    let mockMetadataService;
    // let mock;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    mockValidationUtilService = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'ValidationUtilService',['validateForm','setValidationsForFormControl']);
    mockApiRequestService = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'ApiRequestService',['get']);
    mockFormBuilder = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'FormBuilder',['group']);
    mockCommonUtilty = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'CommonUtility',['serverDOtoUIDODate ','serverDOtoUIDODate','isArrayIterable','initializeLookupList' ]);
    mockCommonUtilty.initializeLookupList.and.returnValue(of([{}])); //--mock return value--
    mockI18nService = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'I18nService',['']);
    mockMultiLingualService=jasmine.createSpyObj('MultiLingualService',['']);
    mockTranslateService=jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslateService',['']);
    mockLookupDataService=jasmine.createSpyObj('LookupDataService',['getLookupData','lookupCacheMap']);
    mockInteractService=jasmine.createSpyObj('InteractService',['']);
    mockWorkqueueService=jasmine.createSpyObj('WorkqueueService',['fetchProducts']);
    mockWorkqueueService.fetchProducts.and.returnValue(of([{}]));
    mockAppMetadataHandler=jasmine.createSpyObj('AppMetadataHandler',['featureFlags']);
    mockNewBusinessAppSettings=jasmine.createSpyObj('NewBusinessAppSettings',['']);
    mockCustomHookService=jasmine.createSpyObj('CustomHookService',['']);
    mockMetadataService=jasmine.createSpyObj('MetadataService',['']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SubmissionDataComponent ],
      providers:[
        {provide:ValidationUtilService,useValue:mockValidationUtilService},
        {provide:ApiRequestService,useValue:mockApiRequestService},
        {provide:FormBuilder,useValue:mockFormBuilder},
        {provide:CommonUtilty,useValue:mockCommonUtilty},
        {provide:I18nService,useValue:mockI18nService},
        {provide:MultiLingualService,useValue:mockMultiLingualService},
        {provide:TranslateService,useValue:mockTranslateService},
        {provide:LookupDataService,useValue:mockLookupDataService},
        {provide:InteractService,useValue:mockInteractService},
        {provide:WorkqueueService,useValue:mockWorkqueueService},
        {provide:AppMetadataHandler,useValue:mockAppMetadataHandler},
        {provide:NewBusinessAppSettings,useValue:mockNewBusinessAppSettings},
        {provide:CustomHookService,useValue:mockCustomHookService},
        {provide:MetadataService,useValue:mockMetadataService},
    ],
    imports:[NgZorroAntdModule, RouterTestingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SubmissionDataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
    
    
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your mock needs to return an Observable.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new, can you explain it a little more? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show `this.commonUtilty.initializeLookupList` code ? You expect it to return an object with an attribute named "exemple", where it doesnt.

Comment: `CommonUtility` is being mocked in your example. When you call `this.commonUtilty.initializeLookupList()`, it needs to return an Object containing Observables (as that is what `getLookupData()` goes looking for). You need to make your mock return that kind of Object.